# How to use a bat file to take data from user and query sqlserver DB

Tags: t-sql, batch-file, user-input, sqlcmd

I'm struggling to get this right. I've searched online and can't find the correct solution.
I want to write a bat file to place on a users desktop that when clicked will ask the user to enter a serial number and use that serial to query the database

database is SQL Server 2012

So far I have a bat file (batfile.bat)

batfile.bat contains

```
sqlcmd -S SERVER1\MSSQL2012 -i C:\KD\SerialNumber.sql -o C:\KD\SerialNumber.txt
```

In SerialNumber.sql I have

```
USE StockDatabase

GO

select * FROM tblStock where SerialNumber like '%1234%'

GO
```

But obviously this doesn't prompt the user for a serial Or use the input in the sql
What I want to do is use the Serial Number inputted by the user in the SQL query

I guess i should do something like

```
set /P var= Enter Serial
```

to get the user input? But how do I use what they have input in the SQL query?

I've changed batfile.bat to;

```
ECHO OFF

set /P var= Enter Serial: %=%

Serial %var% > SerialNumber.sql

sqlcmd -S EUROSERVER2\MSSQL2012 -i C:\KD\SerialNumber.sql -o C:\KD\SerialNumber.txt
```

and the sql to

```
select * FROM tblStock where SerialNumber like '%1234%
```

thinking it made sense but it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass an environment variable's value to your SQL script you can simply refer to it by name inside the script (just surround the environment variable's name with `$()`) or, if you prefer to set it explicitly, use the `-v` switch of `sqlcmd`.

For example (explicit use of the variable):

```
set /P sn= Enter Serial: 
sqlcmd -S SERVER1\MSSQL2012 -i SerialNumber.sql -o SerialNumber.txt -v serial=%sn%
```

Or (implicit use of the variable):

```
set /P serial= Enter Serial: 
sqlcmd -S SERVER1\MSSQL2012 -i SerialNumber.sql -o SerialNumber.txt
```

And, for it to work, your script (`SerialNumber.sql`) would have:

```
select * FROM tblStock where SerialNumber like '%$(serial)%'
```

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx) (MSDN).